# Linear Quadratic Integrator

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, modeling, system-modeling

With a given linear drive system

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
params = {jb -> 870 10^-5 + 75 10^-6, p -> 2, mw -> 0.75, mb -> 10, 
   r1 -> 0.000001, r2 -> 0.000001, 
   jm -> 7800 0.002 \[Pi] (0.165/2)^4 1/2, r3 -> 0.165/2, k1 -> 1, 
   k2 -> 1}; 
displacement = 0;

ke = 1/2 mw (p/(2 \[Pi]) \[Alpha]'[t])^2 + 1/2 jm \[Alpha]'[t]^2  + 
   1/2 mb (p/(2 \[Pi]) \[Alpha]'[t])^2;
kp = mb g h1 + mb g (h1 + h2);
l = ke - kp;
eqns = EulerEquations[l, {\[Alpha][t]}, t] // FullSimplify;
deqns = {First@eqns[[1]] == -r1 \[Alpha]'[t] - f[t] + 4.3 u[t]};
MatrixForm[deqns]

symmodelqr = 
  StateSpaceModel[
    deqns, {{\[Alpha][t], 0}, {\[Alpha]'[t], 0}}, {u[t], 
     f[t]}, {\[Alpha]'[t] 2 \[Pi]/60, f[t]}, t] // FullSimplify;
model = symmodelqr /. params
```

Where $x(t) = \frac{\alpha(t)}{2\pi}$, $u(t)$ is an input between 1-10 to control a servo drive and $f(t)$ is a force disturbance.

I am attempting to design a [linear quadratic integrator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.lqi.html;jsessionid=0c80c75278f664f83419796357d1) force controller,

In the same form as above.

I first designed a lqr controller on the system...a disturbance force will be measured, and with a given motor input u(t) the system should attempt to slow down the linear drive (or back off entirely), to reduce the forces, which appears to work well.

```
init = {0, 0};
times = RandomInteger[{10, 60}, 3];
disturb = (*{0,Table[1 UnitBox[(t-times[[i]])/
  25]\[ExponentialE]^(-1(t-times[[i]])^2),{i,1,Length@
  times}]};*)
  {0, 1 UnitBox[(t - 15)/25] - 1 UnitBox[(t - 40)/25]};
q = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 10}];
r = 1 {{1}};
lineargains = 
  Join[Last@CoefficientArrays[LQRegulatorGains[{model, 1}, {q, r}]] //
     Normal, {ConstantArray[0, 2]}];
First@lineargains
controlmodel = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[model, lineargains];
{alphadot, force} = 
  StateResponse[{controlmodel, init}, disturb, {t, 60}];
Plot[{alphadot, force, disturb[[2]] }, {t, 0, 60}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 Frame -> True]
(*{1., 5.47913}*)
```

[image: block2]

I now have a specific speed profile, or rather, a force profile that I want to give as a reference signal $r$ Where the drive should attempt to keep a quadratically growing force reference tracked, again lowering or increasing the drive speed to keep this in check.

```
feedback = StateSpaceModel[{{}, {}, {{}}, {{1, -1}}}];
integrator = TransferFunctionModel[1/s, s];
tracker = 
 SystemsModelMerge@
  SystemsConnectionsModel[{feedback, integrator, 
    model}, {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {3, 1}, {3, 1} -> {1, 
      2}}, {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}}]
```

My attempt at this however appears to produce nonsense.

```
init2 = {0, 25, 25};
times2 = RandomInteger[{10, 60}, 3];
disturb2 = {1 UnitStep[t], 
   0 UnitBox[(t - 10)/5] - 0 UnitBox[(t - 40)/5]};
q2 = DiagonalMatrix[{1000, 10, 100}];
r2 = 1 {{1}};
lineargains = 
  Join[Last@
     CoefficientArrays[LQRegulatorGains[{tracker, 1}, {q2, r2}]] // 
    Normal, {ConstantArray[0, 3]}];
First@lineargains
controlmodel2 = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[tracker, lineargains];
{int, alphadot2, force2} = 
  StateResponse[{controlmodel2, init2}, disturb2, {t, 100}];
Plot[{int, alphadot2, force2, disturb2 }, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
(*{31.7673, 3.16228, 45.8435}*)
```

[image: other thing]

The Integrator, the way I understand it, should give and keep a tracked signal to the input of the SSM $u(t)$ To keep disturbance forces constant. However, it appears to not do this at all.

Clearly something is wrong. My suspicion is that I've either designed the wrong Statespacemodel in general for force control, or my inputs/outputs are incorrect, or that my SystemsConnectionModel is built incorrectly, However, I can't seem to get anything that makes sense. Are there better eyes out there than mine?

What is the correct way to build an LQI in mma?

(I am completely open to suggestions on how to do it differently or better, however ideally an LQI implementation would be preferred)

Comment: What is `model` and `jm`? I can't reproduce what 'appears to work well' for you. Could you fix the question.

Comment: Oh sorry! Will do as soon as possible, i‘m unfortunately still at work

Comment: @SubaThomas I've updated the code, and retested..it should be working now...let me know if it's not...thanks for having a look!

Comment: `LQRegulatorGains[{model, 1}, {q, r}]` gives the `LQRegulatorGains::idim3` message because `q` is a *2x2* matrix, but `model` only has 1 state variable.

Comment: @SubaThomas ...when running this code exactlyin version 12.0.0 it gives me gains and etc and the plots as in the question.... http://www.lizard-truth.com/wp-content/uploads/controller.nb here is the notebook. I will however re-copy and paste the code again. My apologies.

Comment: @SubaThomas To be honest, if for some reason this still doesn't work, If you had a solution on how to do a LQI properly with a different example in MMA, that'd be for me just as perfect an answer. As the example model isn't as important the LQI method solution. Thanks regardless!

Comment: Things evaluate fine now. Thanks. I hope to look at this again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

For this model it's not possible to design a controller that will track $\alpha '$.

```
{aa, bb, cc, dd} = Normal[model];
StateSpaceModel[{ArrayFlatten[{{0, {{0, -2 π/60}}}, {0, aa}}], ArrayFlatten[{{0}, {bb}}]}]
ControllableModelQ[%]
```

> [image]

However a controller can be designed that tracks $\alpha$.

```
StateSpaceModel[{ArrayFlatten[{{0, {{1, 0}}}, {0, aa}}], ArrayFlatten[{{0}, {bb}}]}]
ControllableModelQ[%]
```

> [image]

Because the controller is using state feedback you will also need an observer. An example of how to do all this can be seen in the 'Differential input controller design' section of the documentation for a [path following robot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/workflow/PathFollowingControl.html). There the reference is $0$ for the robot to stay on course and the disturbance is the path.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, $\dot{\alpha}$ is the state that should be modified to track a profile for $f[t]$....$f[t]$ is the disturbance and the value that needs to be kept in check...as in, I will give a $\dot{\alpha}$ initially... the model will eventually get a disturbance $f[t] $and it should modify $\dot{\alpha}$ to ensure that f[t] stays at a specific level. I would like to develop a force controller. f[t] will eventually not just be a constant value like 0 in the example robot..., but a specific profile. going between 25-40N. I actually don't want to track $\dot{\alpha}$ I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Also to be clear, I can directly measure all states....$\dot{\alpha}$, $\alpha$, and $f[t]$ including torque of motors, electricity and feedforces.

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow you. A disturbance is something outside your control. There is nothing an aircraft controller can do to make the wind gust go away or behave in a certain way. What is can do is use the control inputs available to mitigate the effects of the gust, by regulating variables like the flight path, roll, etc. In the robot example the disturbance is not 0, but the line. It can be any arbitrary profile.

Comment: Perhaps my vocabulary is incorrect...When cutting through a material of any kind with any sort of tool for example when milling, there is a reactionary force directly dependant on the feedrate at which i cut into said material. This reactionary force is a combination of tool pressure, and torques. This is the 'disturbance' And this can be kept in track if I reduce the feedrate in the cutting direction. This is no different to slowing down a circular saw when I try to cut through a piece of wood too fast and the motor RPMS drop...and it stops cutting...I reduce my pushing speed.

Comment: And the motor revs back up again. This is several years old in machining a tracking of cutting force and controlling feedrate...by Siemens AMC controllers https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/996/75338996/att_102241/v1/SI_FH_0313_en.pdf and by toolscope https://cuttingtools.ceratizit.com/gb/en/services/toolscope.html

Perhaps the description of this reactionary feedforce as a disturbance is incorrect. My apologies if this is confusing.

Comment: It appears to me that your model is not capturing what you want to control (the reactionary force). There is an equation for $\alpha$ but not for $f$.

Comment: Yes i would agree...this is a function dependent on velocity...$f(\dot{\alpha})$ of some kind...is this a function specifically required in order for the lqi developement? If so i will attempt to find the coupling between force and velocity.

Comment: Yes. And I'm pretty sure you can find it in the literature.

Comment: I'll read up on it and get back to you, thanks for the help.